# Can't Clone an Assembla repo with smartgit in Ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, assembla, smartgit

I have the newest ubuntu, java, and  installations. Smartgit is installed correctly but I can't figure out how to generate a proper OpenSSH key pair with ubuntu. I tried using the `ssh-keygen -t dsa`
command and It worked on assembla for my profile. Problem is smart git wont accept the private pair because it is not OpenSSH. I downloaded puttygen and I created an OpenSSH key but assembla wont accept the public version. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be uploading your public key to Assembla, in a standard format:

ssh-key_format key label

Where ssh-key_format should be either ssh-dss or ssh-rsa.  The key is your public key - an alphanumeric string with some other characters. The label is a name usually derived from your user and machine and may look like user@machine  There is a blank space between each of the three fields.

Your putty output probably looks like this:

> PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-dss
>   Encryption: none
>   Comment: dsa-key-20120917
>   Public-Lines: 10
>   PUBLIC_KEY
>   Private-Lines: 1
>   PRIVATE_KEY
>   Private-MAC: MAC_ADDRESS

(I replaced the sensitive data with CAPITALIZATION)

You just need to take the beginning (ssh-dss or ssh-rsa) then your PUBLIC_KEY then make ups some label to create a new public key file - use emacs or vim on your computer and save it as id_dsa.pub or id_rsa.pub and upload it to Assembla - should work just fine.

Comment: Try for your response. I am able to achieve that part fine. The matching private key can not be added to Smartgit because it is not in openssh format.

Comment: You should use the original file for smartgit and use the modified file for Assembla.

Comment: The network I was on was preventing a connection to the assembla directory...Doh! As soon as I tried to create the key at home with {ssh-keygen -t rsa }
it worked fine. Thanks for the help.